# Override (monkey-patch?) template of external class

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

Having a fixed custom template in my local application, how can I set it to be used instead of using the original one defined in external add-on?

In my case is about this template: https://github.com/zopefoundation/zope.formlib/blob/master/src/zope/formlib/orderedSelectionList.pt

I tried adding it "orderedSelectionList.pt" in my skins folder, but it seems it is not used (because the original one is not in skins).

I tried also to monkey-patch the class and change the path with `ViewPageTemplateFile('skins/my_folder_with_templates/orderedSelectionList.pt')`. This part is really funny, I can't have it working.

Any suggestion in cases like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override templates with z3c.jbot https://pypi.org/project/z3c.jbot/

Comment: I already have a `template-overrides` folder used with `z3c.jbot` to override templates. But trying with `zope.formlib.orderedSelectionList.pt` is not working - the original template is loaded. Any idea how to debug this?

Comment: From docs: "Any skin-object (e.g. images, templates) on the file system (directory views) can be overridden.". Is this file https://github.com/zopefoundation/zope.formlib/blob/master/src/zope/formlib/orderedSelectionList.pt a skin-object?

Comment: Solved in version 4.5.0 of zope.formlib: https://github.com/zopefoundation/zope.formlib/releases/tag/4.5.0

The question remains for theoretically similar issues: how to override a template that is not in a skins folder of original add-on.